# INSTEAD OF : for each row in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

If I use a `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger like the one in my example, does that apply on every row of my deleted records or do I have to specify it? If it doesn't, how should I do? With using a *select distinct* ? Thank you :)

```
ALTER TRIGGER "rdowner"."TriggerDelete" ON "rdowner"."V_MyTable" 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @idActivity INT

    SELECT  @idActivity = rdowner.V_MyTable.Id,
    FROM deleted

    BEGIN 
         myDeleteRoutine
    END  
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
END CATCH
```

My trigger needs to log the @idActivity, a timestamp and a varchar variable of every deleted rows into another table

Comment: SQL Server triggers **NEVER** work "on every row" - they are called **ONCE** per statement, so if your `DELETE` statement delete 50 rows, your trigger is called **ONCE**, and the `Deleted` pseudo table contains 50 rows which you need to deal with in a **set-based** manner

Comment: Yeah. Writing a trigger and not knowing the absolute fundamental. Please, you can do better.

Comment: @marc_s thanks a lot marc, this is helping me !

Comment: @TomTom i will do better, it's just because i saw oracle codes using *for each row* that's why i was wondering if there is a way to do it, anyway i am just a beginner.

Comment: If you search on "SQL Server trigger for each row" you would find many answers. BTW your trigger does not use the `deleted` table

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you. Oh yeah i just edited it

Comment: OK so now be aware that the select statement is loading into scalar variable `@idActivity`. So what will happen when you delete 10 rows at once is that _one_ of those rows will have it's ID loaded into the variable. To work on each of the 10 rows individually you might have to use a cursor to step through them or you might have a smarter option, depending on what you want to do. For example, if you want to just log the rows that someone tried to delete, you could just run `insert into logtable (col1,col2) slect col1,col2 from deleted`. No cursor required in that case

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me! Well, all i have to do is to log the @idActivity, a timestamp and a varchar variable of every deleted rows into another table.

Comment: Thats what you should have said at the start - I'll edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this:

> > My trigger needs to log the @idActivity, a timestamp and a varchar variable of every deleted rows into another table

then between `BEGIN TRY` and `END TRY` you just need this:

```
INSERT INTO MyLogTable (ID, Column1,Column2, TimeStampColumn)
SELECT ID, Column1,Column2,GETDATE()
FROM DELETED
```

Also as suggested change your error logging to log to a table or remove it altogether

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick, this is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggers allows us what kind of actions ,we intend to perform on base table.Please note that this action doesn't affect base table .We will be having access  to data which will be deleted if we perform this delete.below are some examples which may help you

--create basic trigger:

```
create trigger trg_insd_test
on dbo.test1
instead of delete
as
begin
select 'trigger fired'
select * from deleted
end
```

--now lets delete all rows and see how trigger is fired

```
delete from test1
```

**output:**
even though i tried deleting all rows trigger is fired only once and i have access to all rows which are deleted
[image]

now lets delete in batches:

```
delete top(10) from test1
go 10
```

**Ouput:**
you can see trigger is fired per batch
[image]